# Sequelize: join query adding extra column which is not in model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm applying join query into node's `Sequelize` package for two Models. But it is joining the column of `vendor` model which is not the part of the model property.

*Product Model ::*

```
import { Vendor } from '../vendor/vendor.model'

const Product = SQLize.define('product', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
    }
    product_title: {
        type: new DataTypes.STRING(255),
        allowNull: false
    },
    vendor_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP',
        defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
        allowNull: false
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: 'TIMESTAMP',
        allowNull: true
    }
});

Product.hasOne(Vendor, {foreignKey: 'id'})
Vendor.belongsTo(Product)

export { Product };
```

*Vendor Model ::*

```
const Vendor = SQLize.define('vendor', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
  },
  first_name: {
    type: new DataTypes.STRING(100),
  },
  last_name: {
    type: new DataTypes.STRING(100),
  }
});

export { Vendor }
```

Here is the repository file on which i have performed the sql operation ::

```
public async getProductData() {

    var prodData = Product.findAll({
      subQuery: false,
      include: {
        model: Vendor
      }
    });

    console.log(prodData); 
    return prodData;
  }
```

But all the time it is throwing the Error:

```
 SqlError: (conn=20, no: 1054, SQLState: 42S22) Unknown column 'vendor.ProductId' in 'field list'
```

P.S: 
[DB Structure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de448e)
Sequelize version: 5.21.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined association definitions such as Vendor has a link to a Product but according to your model definition a Product has a link to a Vendor.

Also you forgot to indicate a **foreignKey** option in the second association definition:

```
Product.belongsTo(Vendor, {foreignKey: 'id'})
Vendor.hasOne(Product, {foreignKey: 'id'})
```